# Integer ordinalization in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I'm looking for a way to handle integer ordinalization in Ruby/Rails, ie. "st", "nd", "rd", and "th" suffixes to integers. Ruby on Rails used to extend FixNum with an "ordinalize" method, but that functionality seems to have been deprecated in version 3.

I am currently just using the source for the old Rails method, which is fine... but this seems like functionality that most scripting languages / web frameworks would have built in, and I feel like the folks behind Rails must have had a reason for deprecating the functionality (perhaps it is now available in Ruby proper?).

Please advise!

Comment: I'm not sure if this functionality has been deprecated. Can you post the error you are seeing along with the code that causes it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The method you want is still [ordinalize](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#ordinalize).

[Active_Support](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) was refactored a bit to provide better granularity. Instead of loading in everything at once, you can select smaller chunks depending on what you need.

You can either load everything in Active_Support using `require 'active_support/all'`, or break it down using
 `require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'`:

```
>> require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections' #=> true
>> 1.ordinalize #=> "1st"
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything.

Comment: Well, not *everything*, but at least this thing. :-)

Comment: If you don't want to import everything into your namespace, you can just call ActiveSupport::Inflector(number)

Comment: Which implies you've loaded all of Active Support. Just stick with using the core extensions to avoid loading everything.

Answer (score 0):

Lately (last I knew) there has been a trend to not modify core classes. The Rails-Core mailing list might have a better answer for this one.

It looks like that functionality was moved to [Inflector](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#M000153) from a Fixnum extension which makes sense. Hopefully someone else can confirm this.