# `unsupported: TrueClass` on Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method in my rails `user.rb` model:

```
before_save :set_username

  private

  def set_username
    @users = User.where(first_name == self.first_name)
    same_first_name_array = []
    @users.each do |u|  <<<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE>>>>>>>>
      same_first_name_array << u.first_name
    end

    if same_first_name_array.size == 0
      self.username = first_name
    else
      self.username = first_name + " the " + ordinalize(same_first_name_array.size + 1)
    end
  end
```

When I try to update a `user` I get an `unsupported: TrueClass` error on the line indicated.  I'm not too familiar with `TrueClass` errors, but have a feeling it is being caused by the `each`.  Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

Comment: `@users = User.where(first_name == self.first_name)` problem is on that line, you're query isn't right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@users = User.where(first_name == self.first_name)
```

do you mean

```
@users = User.where(:first_name => self.first_name)
```

The first line you have will evaluate to

```
@users = User.where(true)
```

and then Rails will get confused why you're trying to fetch out users where "true"... probably causing the bug you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I most certainly do mean that!  Thank you.  Now I'm just battling `undefined method 'ordinalize' ` on the last line of the if/else....

Comment: Thay's a different question :)
but have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536855/integer-ordinalization-in-ruby-rails

Comment: Awesome.  I'll check it out.  Thank you!